# Initial term of field expression must be concrete SObject: List trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, update

```
    /*Scenario: Opportunity with existing Products has the Go-Live Date updated.
●   User Input:
○   A User updates an Opportunity with either a different Go-Live Date or Contract Term.
●   Output:
●   There should then be a check triggered on every Product the Opportunity has, re-calculating the Licensing Products with their updated Schedule. 
(i.e. deleting the original schedule for that Product and recreating the amended schedule based on the newly entered date/term.
*/
//pull contract start date + go live date from opp
//if contract start date || go live != to rev schedule start 
//delete revenue schedules and re add them using new dates (each day)
//

trigger OpportunityUpdateTrigger on Opportunity (before update) {
List<OpportunityLineItem> getOLI = new List<OpportunityLineItem>();

List<Product2> getProducts = new List<Product2>();
List<Opportunity> oldOpp = new List<Opportunity>();
List<Opportunity> newOpp = new List<Opportunity>();
List<OpportunityLineItemSchedule> getSchedules = new List<OpportunityLineItemSchedule>();

    for(Opportunity old : trigger.old){
        //get oli and add to list
        for(OpportunityLineItem OLI : [SELECT Id, Product2Id FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE 
                                       OpportunityId=:old.Id]){
            getOLI.add(OLI);
            System.debug('OLI = ' + getOLI);
                                                              }
        //get products related to opportunity line item and add to list
 //ERROR IS HERE       
        for(Product2 p : [SELECT Id, Basis__c, Family FROM Product2 WHERE 
                          Id=:getOLI.Product2Id]){
            getProducts.add(p);
                              System.debug('products : ' + getProducts);
                          }
     //   oldOpp = [SELECT Id, Contract_Start_Date__c, Go_Live_Date__c, Contract_End_Date__c
      //            FROM Opportunity WHERE Id=:old.Id];


System.debug('oldOpp');

            for(Opportunity o : trigger.new){
        try{
            System.debug('Ids' + getOLI +  + 'Products = ' + getProducts);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.debug('The following exception has occurred: ' + e.getMessage());
        }
        if(o.Contract_Start_Date__c != old.Contract_Start_Date__c || o.Go_Live_Date__c != old.Go_Live_Date__c ||
           o.Contract_End_Date__c != old.Contract_End_Date__c){
            System.debug('Date changed!');
               if( getProducts.Family=='Licensing'&& getProducts.Basis__c=='Per Device Per Month' 
                           || getProducts.Basis__c=='Per Site Per Month' ){
                   //do something

        }
        else 
            System.debug('No change in start dates');
            return;
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Note: Im just finding my feet coding in apex so if someone could show me the correct approach to tackle this problem, that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(Product2 p : [SELECT Id, Basis__c, Family FROM Product2 WHERE 
                          Id=:getOLI.Product2Id])
```

You are getting error because you are referring element from list without giving any index
So normally it would look like

```
Id=:getOLI[0].Product2Id
```

But I think you want to query based on all product name so you should do like

```
set<Id> getOLI = new set<Id>();
for(Opportunity old : trigger.old){
        //get oli and add to list
        for(OpportunityLineItem OLI : [SELECT Id, Product2Id FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE 
                                       OpportunityId=:old.Id]){
            getOLI.add(OLI.Product2Id );
for(Product2 p : [SELECT Id, Basis__c, Family FROM Product2 WHERE 
                          Id=:getOLI])
```

You ca  use this code it will solve your problem.

Comment: i have the same issue if( getProducts.Family=='Licensing'&& getProducts.Basis__c=='Per Device Per Month' 
                           || getProducts.Basis__c=='Per Site Per Month' ){
do i just make the getProducts a set also? taking the fields i need?

Comment: @Nebbyyy yes if you want to store only Id based on condition then use Set. Also if solve your problem you can accept the answer.